# How to get selected text id and replace the text with keeping the tags intact with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, selection

I'm creating word by word coloring tool.
Basically user can select few letters from the word and color them separated, so one word can have 2 or more colors.

to keep track of all the words, they all have id and i wanted to know how can i know what letters are selected and what are there word id for selected words, if user has selected multiple words, then i should get each word id with it.

here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FvnPS/29/

i can get the selection, but i don't know how to find there id's for selected words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get ID from your data-id attribute, tetx from text() method. Code is only for concept, not fully developed

```
alert($(this).text() +' ID: '+$(this).data('id'));
```

EDIT: start/end ID's

```
var id = {
    start: null,
    end: null
}


$('word').mouseup(function() {
    alert(getSelectedText() + ' End: ' + $(this).data('id') + ' Start: ' + id.start);
}).mousedown(function(evt) {
    id.start = $(evt.target).data('id')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Gqsu/2/

Comment: how can i get multiple id's for multi-selection of words, like try selecting 'oloring tools' it should return 4 and 5 id

Comment: you will need to get deep into range stuff, not something I'm up on  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range

Comment: is there anyway i can get the html version of the selected text, rather then jst text itself? i might would be putting span for coloring like this http://jsfiddle.net/8Gqsu/3/

Comment: can use slice() method based on start and end ID to filter the word tags

Comment: this all was good, but i just realized i cant tell which letter user selected of a word. like if user select 'n' from mountain word, i wouldn't know which n did he selected from that word. how can i find this out?

Comment: you will have to dig deep into the docs for getSelection and range. All the selection is indexed. The MDN link I gave you above will help

Answer (score 1):

Get it by the event.target attribute - see http://jsfiddle.net/FvnPS/31/

Comment: if i select 'word color' it only shows 'coloring' word, which im assuming only gets coloring id, but not word id. m i wrong?

Comment: This is because it is triggered on mouse up. However, if you want to get any words including the ones from mouse down, then add a mousedown event detection as well and then you can get the id of the mosuedown event and mouseup event and all elements between them will be the words higlighted. If it's the same id, then all good :) same word, else you may need to check the index of the word using .index() for each to see which way to read the elements (words) to get the order correct.

Comment: one last thing im getting issue with. how can i get the selected text including the html tags of it?

Comment: You can use the .outerHTML property which might be included in jQuery's options

Comment: this all was good, but i just realized i cant tell which letter user selected of a word. like if user select 'n' from mountain word, i wouldn't know which n did he selected from that word. how can i find this out?

Comment: Split each word up so each letter is wrapped with a span with an id that is a subset of its parent's id like `<span id="word-100-name"><span id="word-100-1">n</span>...` etc.  Not ideal, but a way to be very very specific.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the id of the first word selected (**first_id**), and the one of the last (**last_id**), obviously all the words in between are selected as well. If only one word is selected both have the same value.

```
$('word').mouseup(function(event) {
    var last_id = parseInt($(this).attr("data-id"));
    var first_id = last_id - getSelectedText().split(" ").length + 1;
});

function getSelectedText() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return '';
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vTgqW/2/